# Unable to init displaylink service for HDMI adapter

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, display

I am trying to get a USB 3.0 to HDMI adapter to work that supports displaylink drivers in `archlinux` with `Xorg` server, doing:

1. I have installed `evdi` for the in development kernel module.
2. I have installed the `displaylink` driver.

```bash
yay -S evdi displaylink
```

3. I have enabled `displaylink.service`.
4. Used the `modesetting` driver with `AccelMethod "none"` and `MatchDriver "evdi"` (in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-evdi.conf`):

```
Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier "DisplayLink"
    MatchDriver "evdi"
    Driver "modesetting"
    Option "AccelMethod" "none"
EndSection
```

This is the official procedure of the [arch-wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/DisplayLink#Installation).

However, when starting or enabling the `displaylink.service`, I get the error:

```
● displaylink.service - DisplayLink Manager Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/displaylink.service; disabled; vendor preset: d>
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-10-05 12:06:37 EDT>
    Process: 24554 ExecStartPre=/sbin/modprobe evdi (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 2ms
lines 1-5/5 (END)
```

Checking the journalctl, I get:

```
The job identifier is 33183.
Oct 05 12:07:34 minnow modprobe[24572]: modprobe: FATAL: Module evdi not found in directory 

Oct 05 12:07:34 minnow systemd[1]: displaylink.service: Control process exited, code=exited,>
Subject: Unit process exited
```

But I have confirmed that `evdi` is correctly installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reviewing the problem, I have noticed that in the last comments of the [displaylink AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/displaylink) package information, it indicates:

> djallits commented on 2022-10-13 21:33 (UTC)
>
> DisplayLink 5.6.1-3 breaks on Linux 6.0.1-arch1-1 x86_64. I am digging into the issue now, >but I just wanted to warn anyone else.

And:

> jmcld commented on 2022-10-14 19:21 (UTC) (edited on 2022-10-14 19:22 (UTC) by jmcld)

> @djallits Linux 6.0.1-arch1-1 x86_64 breaking this is actually a problem with evdi. Fix is mainlined in evdi-git. See https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/evdi#comment-884724 for fix.

So the solution has moved on to uninstall `evdi` and install `evdi-git`.